# Read ZIP file and get data with JSON

Tags: php, json, zip

I try to read JSON stream with an ZIP file

but i can't read this zip for get data with JSON

code :

```
$url = 'https://website.com/wb9f4a8e744a1'; // when we click here is an ZIP file

$z = new ZipArchive();
if ($z->open($url)) {
     $json = $z->getFromName("index.json");
     if ($json) {
            //decode json array
            $json_array = json_decode($json);
            var_dump($json_array);
     }
}
```

tree of zip file :

```
index.json
Objects (folder) // i need to read also this folder and subfolder 
2/9/289892.json
4/z/24522.json
v/9a/45582.json
```

After the code who run (when i unzip folder in FTP)

```
$data = file_get_contents($url); 
$characters = json_decode($data); 
foreach ($characters as $character) {
    echo $character->label . '<br>';
    $dossier = 'objects/' . $character->file;
    $data2 = file_get_contents($dossier); 
    $characters2 = json_decode($data2, true);
```

thank you

Comment: Does something not work? Wrong ZIP file loaded? Wrong files unzipped? Blank page? Any error? Is it `Objects` as in your "tree of zip file" or `objects` as in your code?

Comment: Hello, i have Blank page :/, Objects is an folder contain other sub json files

Comment: `// when we click here is an ZIP file` - first of all, what does that actually mean? Does this URL return a ZIP file download directly - or is this the URL of a page, where you have to click on some link/button first? Second, just because your _browser_ might get a download response when requesting that URL, doesn't necessarily mean your server-side code automatically does as well - perhaps the site has some sort of "bot protection" against "unauthorized" downloads. Did you test this with a _local_ version of the ZIP file first?

Comment: Hello CBroe, this URL return a ZIP file download directly :)

Comment: Have you tried using `Objects/` instead of `objects/` as the folder name in your code? Did you check your PHP/webserver error log? Do you have error reporting turned on to see any errors?

Comment: folder name is : objects ;) i no see errors :/